# Asp.net Core PartialView submits form unnecessarily

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I want to create a Quiz website with Asp. I want to create Quiz, add questions to the quiz, and add answers to the question. Add question button adds a question, but the Addanswer button submits the form instead of adding an answer to the question.

My classes:

```
public class Answer
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Guid QuestionId { get; set; }
```

```
 public class Question
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public Guid QuizId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; } = new List<Answer>() { 
            new Answer() { Content = "Answeeeer" }, 
            new Answer() { Content = "Answeeeer2" },
            new Answer() { Content = "Answeeeer3" }
        };
```

```
public class Quiz
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; } = new List<Question>() { };
```

In front side I have Question and Answer Partial views:

Question Partial View:

```
@model QuizIt_Tests.Entities.Question

<hr style="height: 4px; color: black;" />
<div class="w-100 p-3 px-5 my-3">
    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label">Question</label>
    <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" value="@Model.Content" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
    <div id="answerRows @Model.Id" class="w-75"> 
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers)
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addAnswer @Model.Id">Add Answer</button>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("#addAnswer " + @Model.Id).click(function () {
            console.log("clicked");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddBlankQuestion", "Quizes")',
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#answerRows " + @Model.Id").append(html); },
                                                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });

    </script>
}
```

Answer Partial View:

```
@model QuizIt_Tests.Entities.Answer


<div class="row" style="background-color:red; margin: 20px;">
    <label asp-for="Content" class="control-label">Answer Content</label>
    <input asp-for="Content" class="form-control" value="@Model.Content" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Content" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
 public class QuizesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDBContext _context;

        public QuizesController(ApplicationDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult AddBlankQuestion(Quiz model)
        {
            Question question = new Question(); 
            return PartialView("EditorTemplates/Question", question);
        }
        public IActionResult AddBlankAnswer(Question model)
        {
            return PartialView("EditorTemplates/Answer", new Answer() { QuestionId = model.Id });
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the `type` attribute in the button, which by default is equal to `submit` which causes the form to be submitted, to change its behavior, change the `type` value to `button` as follows.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addAnswer @Model.Id">Add Answer</button>
```